# geometry_column table not automatically exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0

I use PostgreSQL 9.2 but geometry_column table not automatically exist like spatial_ref_sys table, but if I use PostgreSQL 9.1 it's exist.
How to make geometry_column automatically exist in PostgreSQL 9.2? because I also need to use pg_routing

Comment: Check the versions (`SELECT PostGIS_version()`). Until PostGIS 1.5, `geometry_columns` was a TABLE, but in 2.0 it was changed to a VIEW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GIS functions and the geometry_column, spatial reference tables etc do not exist by default in PostgreSql. You need to install the PostGIS extension (which you can add to an existing instance of PostgreSql or add when you install a fresh instance of PostgreSql).

Go to the [PostGIS Getting Started](http://postgis.net/install) documentation and follow the directions on how to CREATE EXTENSION, or use EnterpriseDB's 'Stack Builder' utility.  Start Stack Builder and highlight the PostGIS option relevant to your installation of PostrgreSql (you can have more than one version on a machine).

The easiest way to setup PostGIS is to use the precompiled installer bundles that allow you to add the PostGIS and pgRouting extensions on installation.  These are available from [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) or can be downloaded from the [PostGIS site](http://postgis.net/windows_downloads).  The postGIS link explains a number of options for obtaining PostGIS.

Comment: I already use postgis 2.0 and pg_routing, but my database doesnt show up on my css page, is there any different script between postgreSQL 9.2 and 9.1 to connect with css page (.map file) ??